# H00035: access to "file.php" denied, how to properly setup SELinux?

Tags: permissions, httpd, selinux, vagrant

I have been struggling for the last days with this issue and so far I am not able to find any solution. The issue in a few words is (error message):

> H00035: access to index.php denied because search permissions are
>   missing on a component of the path

Where this app is running?

- the host is Windows 10
- this is a VM running inside VirtualBox and managed by Vagrant
- CentOS Linux release 7.5.1804 (Core)
- Apache/2.4.33 (IUS)
- PHP 7.2.6 (no that it matters but just in case)
- SELinux: Enforcing

What I have tried so far:

- Ran the following commands in the box: It worked? **NO** (found [here](https://superuser.com/a/883972/309325))

  ```
  find /var/www -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
  find /var/www -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \;
  ```
- Ran the following commands in the box: It worked? **NO** (found [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/720162))

  ```
  chcon -R -t httpd_sys_content_t /var/www
  ```

Tried everything in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25190043/apache-permissions-are-missing-on-a-component-of-the-path), It worked? **NO**.

What I did tried and works? Disable SELinux!!! So for sure it's a SELinux miss configuration.

Permissions at `/var/www` looks like follow:

```
# namei -mo /var/www/api/public/index.php
f: /var/www/api/public/index.php
 dr-xr-xr-x root    root    /
 drwxr-xr-x root    root    var
 drwxrwxr-x vagrant vagrant www
 drwxrwxr-x vagrant vagrant api
 drwxrwxr-x vagrant vagrant public
 -rwxrwxr-- vagrant vagrant index.php
```

What else I can try here to fix the issue? I know the easy path would be "disable SELinux" but I do not want to do it it would be better to learn how
to do things right :)

This box was built using [Puphpet](https://puphpet.com/) and I can share it. Let me know if you need it for testing purposes.

**UPDATE #1:**

@hbruijn's answer gave me the idea to change the owner from `vagrant` to Apache `www-data` and the `H00035` is gone, however I got a new one.

```
// Before
synced_folder:
    folder1:
        owner: vagrant
        group: vagrant
        source: ../../www/html
        target: /var/www
        sync_type: default

// After
synced_folder:
    folder1:
        owner: www-data
        group: www-data
        source: ../../www/html
        target: /var/www
        sync_type: default
```

The error as it is right now:

> (13)Permission denied: [client 192.168.50.1:2048] AH00529:
>   /var/www/api/public/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess
>   file, ensure it is readable and that '/var/www/api/public/' is
>   executable

This is the output from @hbruijn's answer:

```
# ls -lZ /var/www/
drwxrwxr-x. www-data www-data system_u:object_r:vmblock_t:s0   api/
-rwxrwxr--. www-data www-data system_u:object_r:vmblock_t:s0   index.html*
```

I have ran the same command again: `find /var/www -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \;` but it did not change anything at all which mean permissions remains the same as before.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably rooted in the fact that you expose part of the host file system as /var/www data in your VirtualBox VM.

Obviously Windows does not have the required file attributes to provide SELinux contexts.

So your VM uses a default security context instead.

The default security context for an "unknown" file system is not a context that aligns well with running a web server.
Check with `ls -lZ /var/www/`. Your webserver needs something like

```
drwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 /var/www/html
```

and currently you're probably getting something different like:

```
drwxrwxrwx. vagrant vagrant system_u:object_r:vmblock_t:s0 /var/www/api
```

You can try to manually force the correct SELinux context as a mount option:

```
mount -o remount,context="system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0" /var/www
```

and if that works as intended (check with `ls -Z`) you can probably add that to the mount options is /etc/fstab or your vagrant file

Comment: The command is failing `# mount -o remount,context="system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0" /var/www unknown mount option relatime` not sure in how to fix it

Comment: Also could you take a look to my update in the OP?

Answer (score 0):

`restorecon -vRF /var/www` will restore the default security context for all files below /var/www. If you haven't changed selinux policies, that should fix it. As a note, if you moved the files elsewhere, you could change those contexts by doing:

```
semanage fcontext -a -e /var/www /somewhere/www
restorecon -vRF /somewhere/www
```

In your case, it shouldn't benecessary because /var/www already has defined default labels (eg contexts), but a different directory would not, so you have to change them and then apply them. You can get a idea of pathname to context mappings with `grep www  /etc/selinux/targeted/contexts/files/file_contexts`,

Also, chmod only affects discretionary controls (file permissions), not the mandatory controls (policies) of selinux. Both need to be right for it to work, but if you disabled selinux and it worked, you shouldn't need to do it again.

In addition, /var/log/messages should log all selinux errors and tell you the object that's blocking access. If you do a temporary 'setenforce 0' that will change selinux to permissive mode so that all actions will work but you'll still get the log errors which you can fix them all before turning it back on. If that fails, look at installing the packages setroubleshoot and setroubleshoot-server which will give you even more info.